# Are there ports for tex and pdftex on FreeBSD?

Tags: pdftex, installing, freebsd

I just want to install tex and pdftex, are there ports for them on FreeBSD, so that I can install them by some cmd like "pkg install tex".

Comment: https://www.freshports.org/print/texlive-full/ but it's pretty old (TeX Live 2015).  FreeBSD is [officially supported](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc.html#platforms) by upstream TeX Live, so you just install it from https://tug.org/texlive.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to install the FreeBSD package `pkg install print/texlive-texmf`.  Installing [the UNIX version of TeX Live from TUG](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) should also work.

Comment: I have tried this cmd, but still cannot find pdftex and tex.

Comment: I also tried installing from TUG. But it shows " I can't find the format file 'tex.fmt' " when I ran pdftex and tex.

Comment: Which directory did you install to, and what does `which pdftex` show?

Comment: "which pdftex" shows "pdftex not found". And when installing from TUG, the prefix is /usr/local.

Comment: You need to add the directory containing the binaries to your `PATH`. You can `find /usr/local/texlive/ -name "latex" -print` if you’re not sure where exactly it is.

Comment: You should also have gotten a message at the end of the installation telling you what to add to your `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH`. If, for example, you installed to `/usr/local/texlive/`, you might add the commands `MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH` to your `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`.

Comment: I can find the binary of pdftex. But when I ran it, it showed "I can't find the format file 'pdftex.mt'". How to solve it?

Comment: I don’t run FreeBSD myself. You should start by adding its location to the start of your `PATH`, and see if that fixes it. You also want to re-run `tlmgr update --self --all`, which updates your distribution and should also regenerate all those files.  On some systems, you might need to run it as `sudo $(kpsewhich tlmgr) update --self --all`.